# Ruby, how to swap the elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

How do I swap an(example) array's second and third elements? I tried the following

```
def swap_elements(array)
array = ["blake", "ashley", "scott"]
    array[1], array[2] = array[2], array[1]
end
```

but I get

```
: ["scott", "ashley"]
```

I lost the first[0] element

Comment: Whatever value of `array` that is passed to `swap_elements` is changed to `["blake", "ashley", "scott"]` within the method. You therefore need to remove the line that defines `array` within the method. (Perhaps put that line before the line that executes the method, `swap_elements(array)`.  When `array = ["blake", "ashley", "scott"]`, the statement `array[1], array[2] = array[2], array[1]` indeed returns `["scott", "ashley"]` but that is the new value of `[array[1], array[2]]`, not the new value of `array`. You need to add the line `array` as the last statement in the method.

Comment: Does the array always have 3 elements?

Comment: To create a new array with swapped elements, `array.values_at(0, 2, 1)` would work. For more than 3 elements, you can use `array.values_at(0, 2, 1, 3..-1)`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this - this is a functional approach that doesn't mutate the original array:

```ruby
def swap_elements(array)
  # yields the array to the block
  array.then do |first, *rest| # deconstruct the array  
    rest.reverse # swap the places of 2 & 3
        .unshift(first) # put the first back in
  end
end
```